# How to see grails documentation on mouse hover?

Tags: grails, ggts

I am very new to Grails I want to get info about each function just hovering the mouse as I did in java/android via Windows->Preferences->Java->Editor->hover.

I am using Groovy/Grails Tool Suite 
Version: 3.6.4.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can gather playing with settings on my local GGTS 3.6.3, the same settings location that you've given:

`Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Hover`

Appear to apply to my `.groovy` files as well.  I have the following enabled:

- Combined Hover - with `Pressed key modifier while hovering` left blank
- Externalized String
- Javadoc
- Source